# How to compile a single JAVA file and put it back into WAR?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have searched this, and there is  similar situation but not an exact one.
Being a beginner I need full instructions.I have the need to compile a single Java file and put it back into an existing (compiled) Java application. The source of this Java code is not available to me, therefore I cannot compile the entire project.
I have decompiled a singe class file i needed, made changes to it and now  want to put its corresponding class file back into the WAR.
I do not want to use ANT or maven rather want to use eclipse to do the compiling. I do not know how can I resolve the dependencies my java file will have

I obviously do not want to decompile entire application.

I do have the WAR file

Thanks!

Comment: If you are complete beginner, you should go and learn to program in Java before you attempt to mess around with decompiling / modifying / compiling Java code.  Then we won't need to give you "full instructions" that you probably won't understand anyway.  (Sorry ... but that is a fact ... not a reflection on your intelligence.)

Comment: To add to my answer: you should explain what you are trying to achieve, in order to let us explain how it can be done with a more sustainable process.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the updated class file in exploded war and again create a war of it.

Comment: @sahana - That is what the compiler is for!

Comment: If that class is independent then you can do it as it will get compiled from command prompt else it might be a tough call to updated existing class file as you need to decompile and then compile again.

Comment: My Java file is dependent on other files in the package

Answer (score 0):

You can't really put a single file into the WAR. What you can do is access the location where server keeps unzipped war and replace the old file with new one.

Answer (score 0):

From a file format point of view, a WAR is nothing more than a zip file. You can open it using any utility able to process zipfiles, like Winzip, for example. So you can unzip your WAR file, add your compiled class at the location corresponding to its package and zip it again.

But I really don't recommend such a process. It's very likely to be a very, very bad idea. It will probably cause all kind of problems later, because in a regular process, a war file is build from a project, and obviously, you are adding a file which is not part of the project the war file was built from. So at some point, you will want to rebuild the war file and you will lose the changes you made to the file you added.

But it can be done...

On how to get a compiled classfile: if you see your source file in Eclipse without any red annotation, you probably already got it on your file system. Just take a look using a file explorer or something. If you can't see it, press Control+B in Eclipse to build (those instructions don't work for a Maven project).

You should add your file to the project the war file was generated from, in order to keep your whole work in one consistent unit. So you can build over and over again without worrying about changes like the one you plan here. Think: one click to build your whole, complete, usable warfile.

Comment: Thanks! But Since I do not have the source code, is it possible that I import my war as a set of jars which would help me in compiling my file(considering my java file has some dependencies)?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you're looking for?

http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/

It can replace smaller code changes inside Java classes, while deployed in a server. Thus it can spare you deploy time. It has a limitation though: if you do large-scale modifications, then you need to recompile the whole .war anyways, and then reconnect to your server.